# pandas function to create combined column based on dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to create a weighted column in a `pandas.DataFrame`

I have a python `dictionary` with the keys being the `pandas.DataFrame` column names and the values the corresponding weights.

I would like to create a new column which is weighted based on the `dictionary` and reference `pandas.DataFrame` column values.

> What is an efficient way to do this considering my `dictionary` configuration will change and contain "misconfiguration" ?

**As an example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
weights = {'IX1' : 0.3, 'IX2' : 0.2, 'IX3' : 0.4, 'IX4' : 0.1}
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['IX1', 'IX2', 'IX3'])

##Desired output --- manually combine
df['Composite'] = df['IX1']*0.3 + df['IX2']*0.2 + df['IX3']*0.4
```

**I would like the code to still run even if the `pandas.DataFrame` is missing columns**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create variable for same values for columns and keys in dictionary by [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html), then select this columns and use matrix multiplication with [`dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with `Series` from dict filtered for same columns only:

```
df['Composite'] = df['IX1']*0.3 + df['IX2']*0.2 + df['IX3']*0.4

cols = df.columns.intersection(weights.keys())
df['Composite1'] = df[cols].dot(pd.Series(weights)[cols])
print (df)
        IX1       IX2       IX3  Composite  Composite1
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738   1.000742    1.000742
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278   0.654868    0.654868
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219   0.213468    0.213468
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274   0.733698    0.733698
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863   0.430192    0.430192
5  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158   0.316855    0.316855
6  0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990  -1.098095   -1.098095
7  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165   0.072107    0.072107
8  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759   0.408357    0.408357
9 -0.187184  1.532779  1.469359   0.838144    0.838144
```